# ¿Como utilizar la etiqueta <br> en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Empiezo con contarles que no tengo experiencia con jquery y en este momento tan solo quiero dar un espacio cada vez que agrego un input pero no encuentro la forma, he puesto la etiqueta aquí y no funciona:

```
$(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" />   ');
```

Les dejo mi código completo:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var iCnt = 0;

// Crear un elemento div añadiendo estilos CSS
var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px', border: '1px dashed',
borderTopColor: 'blue', borderBottomColor: 'blue',
borderLeftColor: 'blue', borderRightColor: 'blue'
});

$('#btAdd').click(function() {
if (iCnt <= 10) {

iCnt = iCnt + 1;

// Añadir caja de texto.
$(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" />   ');


if (iCnt == 1) {

var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
$(divSubmit).append('<input type=submit name="btn-add" onclick="GetTextValue()"' +
'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />');

}

$('#main').after(container, divSubmit);
}
else { //se establece un limite para añadir elementos, 20 es el limite

$(container).append('<label>Limite Alcanzado</label>');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable');
$('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

}
});

$('#btRemove').click(function() { // Elimina un elemento por click
if (iCnt != 0) { $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); iCnt = iCnt - 1; }

if (iCnt == 0) { $(container).empty();

$(container).remove();
$('#btSubmit').remove();
$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt')

}
});

$('#btRemoveAll').click(function() { // Elimina todos los elementos del contenedor

$(container).empty();
$(container).remove();
$('#btSubmit').remove(); iCnt = 0;
$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt');

});
});

// Obtiene los valores de los textbox al dar click en el boton "Enviar"
var divValue, values = '';

function GetTextValue() {

$(divValue).empty();
$(divValue).remove(); values = '';

$('.input').each(function() {
divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
padding:'5px', width:'200px'
});
values += this.value + '<br />'
});

$(divValue).append('<p><b>Tus valores añadidos</b></p>' + values);
$('body').append(divValue);

}




</script>
```

Comment: La pregunta dice "he puesto la etiqueta aquí" pero no señala dónde ni cómo.

Comment: Sii dices que lo has puesto, pero no la veo en tu codigo

Comment: @Rúben  La he colocado asi: $(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" /> '+'<br>   ');

Comment: @Risa__B La he colocado asi: $(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' + 'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" /> '+'<br> ');

Comment: Tambien he probado el css como han dicho otros compañeros.

Comment: sino te han funcionado, intenta esto $(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id="tb' + iCnt + ' " placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" /> <br />');

Comment: @DanielTreviño por favor usa el boton [edit] para agregar la informacion que se te va pidiendo a la pregunta.

Comment: @Risa__B si encuentras una solucion viable, ponlo en una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias a todos al parecer los cambios que realizo en mi host en cuanto al diseño tardan en realizarse, me funciono usando css.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código final que usaste? Así puede ser útil para otra gente en el futuro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esta muy bien lo que propone @dengue8830, yo haria:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    required: 'required',
    name: 'fields[]',
    class: 'input',
    id: 'tb' + iCnt,
    placeholder: 'Producto' + iCnt
}).appendTo( container );
```

Y luego la clase

```
.input{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: amigo ya probe tu codigo y sigue sin funcionar. agregue la clase .input a un archivo css aparte, esta referenciado.

Comment: depende de los espacios si es a la derecha este estilo, si es abajo, margin-bottom: 10px, si es a todos lados solo margin: 10px;

Answer (score 0):

Puede intentar con

```
$(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" />&nbsp;');
```

Para agregar un espacio al final ó

```
$(container).append('<input type=text required="required" name ="fields[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'placeholder="Producto ' + iCnt + '" /><br/>');
```

Para dar un enter

Comment: probe tu codigo pero sigue sin agregarme el espacio, alguien seria tan amable de probarlo con mi codigo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución más limpia es usar css. Si usas otros elementos HTML (como br) para lograr un estilo específico luego será difícil de mejorar o corregir, sin mencionar lo poco responsivo que será tu vista.

Ya tenés la clase input, así que el CSS para agregar un espacio podía ser algo así:

```
.input {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Estarías agregando un espacio a la derecha de cada input

Comment: Podrias aclarar un poco mas tu respuesta? se reporto como de baja calidad por su extension. por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Gracias, he editado para explayarme más

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución te crea una etiqueta br debajo del input.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var input =$('<input type="text"></input>');
  var br = $('<br/>');
  var parrafo = $('<p>Hola tengo un br arriba</p>');
  $("body").append(input);
  input.after(br);
  br.after(parrafo);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```